# Email client support for PNG images in HTML email

Tags: html, image, email, gmail, embedded-resource

Will the following email clients show an embedded PNG image in HTML email?

. Outlook
. AOL
. Eudora 
. Thunderbird
. Gmail
. Hotmail
. Windows Live Mail

Comment: I *think* this would be more of a superuser.com question.

Comment: I think the question is applicable in the sense that I want to know what kinds of images I can use in generated emails. It is in the same class as which browsers support PNGs? or How do I get IE to support PNGs.

Answer (score 12):

This site has a lot of information regarding email client support for features:

http://www.campaignmonitor.com

Of particular interest to me in the past have been CSS support in email clients.  (Outlook 2008 sucks the most!)

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

And this link on that site might help you directly:

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/2695/lotus-notes-doesnt-support-png-images/

Answer (score 3):

The only clients that do not support .png images are lotus notes 6.5 and 7.0.

Comment: And any version of Outlook prior to Outlook 2007 won't support 24-bit PNG's.